# How to make grid dynamically by clicking a button

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a list populated by an array of strings.

I want to create a grid that will have 3 columns max per row. It will begin empty and then it will create a column for each list item whenever it is selected.
Lets say i have an array

lets say i have a list populated by this array `["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"]`
When i select `ipsum` for instance it should create a new column on the grid dynamically for `ipsum`.

The grid should have just 3 columns per row

I have no idea what to try

Here's all I have

**HTML**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of itemlist">
         {{item}}
    </ion-item>
<ion-list>
```

Let's say I want a grid down here:

```
<ion-grid>
//How do i make this grid to do what i explained above
</ion-grid>
```

then for ts

```
listitems = ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolor"];
```

I expect to have a grid that will be updated with columns when i click on any list item but I haven't been able to find a way to do it

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/grid check this doc

Comment: Hi, i have checked it out but i dont think i understand what they are saying. Please can you give maybe a sample code thanks